# How can I dynamically load two of the same user control on runtime without allowing changes in one control to affect the other?

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, user-controls

I'm having trouble re-using a user control in WPF and I hope you can help.

On runtime, I am creating new instances of this user control to appear in a WPF grid. The user control consists of a text box and a list box, where user input in the text box filters the results in the list box. Say for this example that I create two of this same user control dynamically at runtime which share the same ViewModel. However, when I run the application, if I enter something in the second user control text box, it reflects in the listbox of BOTH of the user controls. I only want it to reflect in its own listbox.

Here is the picture of the issue on the front end. The highlighted input is reflected in both list boxes but shouldn't:

[image]

Here is the User Control XAML:

```
<UserControl x:Class="SCM_AllergyRecModule.SearchAndSelectView"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
         mc:Ignorable="d">
<StackPanel Width="150">
    <TextBox x:Name="Filter" Text="{Binding Path=Filter, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
    <ListBox Height="50" 
           ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Allergens}"
           IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True"
           SelectedItem="{Binding Path=SelectedAllergen}">         
    </ListBox>
</StackPanel>
```

And the ViewModel for the User Control:

```
namespace SCM_AllergyRecModule
{
public class SearchAndSelectViewModel
{
    private ICollectionView allergens;
    private string selectedAllergen;
    private string filter = "";      

    public string Filter
    {
        get
        {
            return this.filter.ToUpperInvariant();
        }
        set
        {
            if (this.filter != value)
            {
                this.filter = value;
                this.Allergens.Refresh();
            }
        }
    }

    private bool ContainsFilter(object item)
    {
        var product = item as string;
        if (product == null)
        {
            return false;
        }

        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(this.Filter))
        {
            return true;
        }

        if (product.ToUpperInvariant().Contains(this.Filter))
        {
            return true;
        }

        return false;
    }

    public SearchAndSelectViewModel()
    {
        this.allergens = CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(MainWindow.scmAllergens);
        this.allergens.Filter = ContainsFilter;
    }

    public ICollectionView Allergens
    {
        get
        {
            return this.allergens;
        }
    }

    public string SelectedAllergen
    {
        get
        {
            return this.selectedAllergen;
        }
        set
        {
            if (this.selectedAllergen != value)
            {
                this.selectedAllergen = value;
            }
        }
    }
}
}
```

Here is the dynamic loading of the User Control on runtime in the Main Window (please ignore the naming for now):

```
SearchAndSelectView ssvAllergenSearch = new SearchAndSelectView();
            ssvAllergenSearch.DataContext = new SearchAndSelectViewModel();
            controlName = "ssvAllergenSearch" + (rowCounter.ToString() + allergenColumn.ToString());
            ssvAllergenSearch.Name = controlName;
            this.RegisterName(controlName, cmbAllscriptsCategory);
            Grid.SetRow(ssvAllergenSearch, rowCounter);
            Grid.SetColumn(ssvAllergenSearch, allergenColumn);
            DynamicGrid.Children.Add(ssvAllergenSearch);
```

Comment: If you're creating UI in your codebehind you're probably doing something wrong.  Research ItemsControls/ContentControls and DataTemplates.

Comment: I will. I honestly didn't know of any other way to dynamically create controls though. The amount of controls created is based on the input of a previous window from the user so it varies.

Comment: Well, now you have something to search for :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe this is the offending line:

```
this.allergens = CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(MainWindow.scmAllergens);
```

I assume you only have one instance of MainWindow, and thereby only one instance of scmAllergens. By calling `CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView`, you are getting the same `CollectionViewSource` both times. Manually create a new instance instead:

```
var cvs = new CollectionViewSource();
cvs.Source = MainWindow.scmAllergens;
this.allergens = cvs.View;
```

Comment: Thank you! That was it. I had been thinking around MainWindow.scmAllergens as being the culprit but didn't know how to make it reference different instances of that list.

Answer (score 1):

If they're sharing the same viewmodel, that's your issue. Your controls are being bound by DataContext to the same source, so the targets link back to the same instance which causes a change in one to change the other via two-way bindings. Instantiate separate models for each and your problem will be solved. Building the control as a concrete control (where the code-behind is also the viewmodel) eliminates this problem and is the MVVM best practice in most cases.